# array of objects not passing into Scope property of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller ToolCtrl as follows:

```
function ToolCtrl() {

var vtc = this;
vtc.selectedItem = [ {"id":768,"coOwnerChoruspath":null,"coOwnerLocation":null,"counterPartOwner":"NA","counterPartOwnerEmail":"NA","criticality":"Mandatory","dlinks":[],"edvCategory":null,"filterItems":[{"id":309,"genericFilter":{"id":47,"activeFlag":"tool","description":"Which password policy does it use?","title":"Password Policy used"},"item":"N/A","itemDesc":"Not Applicable"},{"id":315,"genericFilter":{"id":49,"activeFlag":"tool","description":"Which environments does it access?","title":"Environments accessed"},"item":"PPT","itemDesc":"PPT, QAT, STG, AP1, DRPPT"},........];
}
```

I have a directive toolDir with the above controller as follows:

```
.directive('toolDir', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,

    controller: ToolCtrl,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    scope: {
        selectedItem: '=',
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        var selectedItem = scope.selectedItem;
        transclude(scope, function (clone) {
            element.append(clone);
        });
    }
    }

    });
    })
```

I have used the directive as follows:

```
<html code>
<tool-dir selected-item="$ctrl.selectedItem">{{$ctrl.selectedItem}}</tool-dir>
```

There is no data being displayed here.

I expect an output as :

```
[ {"id":768,"coOwnerChoruspath":null,"coOwnerLocation":null,"counterPartOwner":"NA","counterPartOwnerEmail":"NA","criticality":"Mandatory","dlinks":[],"edvCategory":null,"filterItems":[{"id":309,"genericFilter":{"id":47,"activeFlag":"tool","description":"Which password policy does it use?","title":"Password Policy used"},"item":"N/A","itemDesc":"Not Applicable"},{"id":315,"genericFilter":{"id":49,"activeFlag":"tool","description":"Which environments does it access?","title":"Environments accessed"},"item":"PPT","itemDesc":"PPT, QAT, STG, AP1, DRPPT"},]
```

Comment: Create a runnable demo that reproduces issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be perfect. I replicated your code on my machine and it is working the way you are expecting it to. If that is not working on your machine try to create the function ToolCtrl inside the directive's scope. (I am assuming that name of your app is 'angularApp');

Something like this :

```
angularApp.directive('toolDir', function(){

  function ToolCtrl(){
    var vtc = this;
    vtc.selectedItem = [{key1:'value1'},{key2:'value2'}];
  }

  return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      transclude: true,  
      controller:ToolCtrl,
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      scope: {
          selectedItem: '=',
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
          var selectedItem = scope.selectedItem;
          transclude(scope, function (clone) {
              element.append(clone);
          });
      }
      }
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please look at that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/gedkLbsc/1/). 
It's a working example of what you are trying to do.

I copy/past your code, it seems you didn't write the controller.

```
function ToolCtrl($scope) {
   this.selectedItem = $scope.selectedItem;
}
```